# Share question/answer links to LinkedIn

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion, sharing

Presently we have the share link option to Facebook and Twitter. Why not LinkedIn?

Edit:

Why LinkedIn?

LinkedIn is place for professional networking and I believe if I shared a question/answer there I would have more developers/programmers looking into it and it would be the right kind of promotion of Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is a limit to how many "sharing" links you should show, but I don't think we're near that limit yet. The other thing to consider is how much traffic would it generate?

Comment: didn't even know there was a limit i hadn't shared any until now .

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a limit **to the number of links shown** in the code - I was thinking more of the space they'd take up. I would be very surprised if there was a limit **to the number of links you can share** as that would defeat their purpose.

Comment: Who can we contact in this regard? and How?

Comment: I've also made the same request on the feedback section of LinkedIn - can't harm I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Sharing on linkedin is experimentally enabled.

We will re-evaluate this in a month or two and see how much it is being used, to determine if we will carry it forward or drop it.

Comment: so i guess linkedin didn't make the cut. care to share any metrics or feedback on this you may have collected that led to this decision?

Comment: see http://twitter.com/#!/michaelpryor/status/111516578725629952

Comment: would be nice to give this another go. a lot can change in 2 years? I know it's a feature I would use.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see more integration to LinkedIn, but I'm not sure if SO Careers has too many crossovers; like uploading CVs and job adverts for example.  But as SO will never be a social network linking to the best career building social network would benefit both SO and LinkedIn.

I would be more than impressed if SO spoke to LinkedIn and got LinkedIn to allow **SO flair** to be added as a Linked In application - in the same way that your Amazon Reading List, GitHub projects, Tweets, some blog types and so on can be added to your LinkedIn profile.

I think SO flair as a LinkedIn application will guide many more people from LinkedIn to SO as it would not put off non-technical people - and it would enhance the implicit value of the SO reputation.

Comment: I mention SO Careers and then checked my email to find out that I had been sent an SO Careers 2.0 invite earlier today - spooky.

Comment: +1 i feel the same to. it would definitely good for every one if a decent level of integration is achieved.