# Why can't we share on LinkedIn anymore?

Tags: discussion, support, linkedin

Well the title says it all.

Why is there no link to share on LinkedIn anymore?

[image]

[I realized this from an [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116729/155556)]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [Jeff answered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94802/135201) those links were experimental.  The LinkedIn one simply wasn't being used, not to nearly the volume of the others...so we removed the extra clutter from the UI.

It will likely be replaced with Google+, given they ever provide an officially supported link-only way to share.