# Soooo... LinkedIn is the new G+?

Tags: bug, status-completed, serverfault, share-this, google-plus

[image]

Clicking the LinkedIn logo loads the Google+ sharing.

Comment: So people actually **do** click on the LinkedIn buttons

Comment: @AdamRackis - I certainly never do, thats why it caught my eye. I don't even really know what LinkedIn does, only that I thought it was an odd place to share questions you'd asked (maybe answers?)

Comment: It's like Jon Stewart said: "Oh, I though LinkedIn was an email clogging service"

Comment: You should probably mention this was on Server Fault (I assume), since the sprites.png for Stack Overflow (and Gaming, for completeness) appears to be correct.

Comment: I thought the LinkedIn link had been removed a while ago. I suspect some caching issues here.

Comment: Indeed, @Tim, on other sites I'm [seeing G+, Facebook and Twitter, no LinkedIn](http://i.stack.imgur.com/51ZUv.png) and indeed I think I recall that LinkedIn would be dropped.

Comment: Hmmm, [the Recent Changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) claims LinkedIn was removed on 2011-09-09... See also [Why can't we share on LinkedIn anymore?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116730/why-cant-we-share-on-linkedin-anymore/116732#116732)

Comment: @Arjan I guess there was no point in updating the sprite file for a ton of sites, since they could just remove the link (presumably since they had to update all the files to add G+, they used it to replace LinkedIn in all cases but this one)

Comment: Will be fixed shortly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We used the same sprite position since we had the offsets in the CSS for where LinkedIn used to be, this was a big time saver across all the site themes.  *Buuuuuut*, we missed some sprites: Stack Apps and Server Fault.

A build is rolling out now with new sprites and cache breakers to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

I headed over to Server Fault to [check the sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK9bK.png), as Tim hinted this might be the source, and can confirm that the LinkedIn icon is still present. You can refresh all you like, alter the version query value, it's definitely still there.

After going through the full list of sites over on the Stack Exchange site, I can find no others where this occurs (I think all beta sites use the same one, which I only thought to find out on the last two).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they just updated this to include G+, and get rid of LinkedIn as per this screenshot:

[image: G+]

If you refresh or wait a little while, it should change.

Answer (score 1):

It shows a Google+ icon there for me. Perhaps you're using an old version of the CSS sprite image? If you [look directly at the CSS sprite image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5), there is no LinkedIn icon there at all.

Answer (score 1):

The logo changed to a little `g+` icon for me when I reloaded this morning. You can see it near the bottom of this sprite:

[image]

I assume you'll get the updated sprite soon.

Comment: Composite image -> Sprite. We call them sprites.

Comment: @jcolebrand: thanks buddy! I had that written initially and then changed when "composite image" when I thought that perhaps "sprite" was a bad habit I picked up somewhere. Since, you know, sprites are easy to bitblt across a display, but there's no bitblting here....

Comment: Hey, at least you know about bitblting :D How many people know that one?