# Is there an option to share posts on LinkedIn and have it count for the Publicist badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, sharing, publicity-badges

I have a lot of technical friends from LinkedIn, so I would like to share questions or answers from [Magento.SE](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is no LinkedIn option when I click on the share link beneath the post.

1. I know I can directly go to LinkedIn and share, but why isn't LinkedIn added as a share option?
2. If I go directly to LinkedIn and share, will it be counted towards the  **Publicist** gold badge?

Comment: Although the first point of the question is answered by the duplicate, the second is certainly not. These questions are related but not duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Currently, LinkedIn isn't one of the options for sharing. However, as you mentioned, you can copy the link to share it there. Since there are many social media providers out there, I don't think every single one can be supported. The supported ones include Google+, Facebook and Twitter which are the major social media providers.

   As mentioned, there [aren't a lot of people sharing on LinkedIn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116730/why-cant-we-share-on-linkedin-anymore/116732#116732).

---

2. Yes, if you are sharing directly, you will earn the badge. However, you must use the link from the 'Share' button as it includes your userid.

   (share link) `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289248/327561` (327561 is the userid).

   (normal link) `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289248` (This won't work)