# Add LinkedIn to "Know someone who can answer?"

Tags: feature-request, share-this, linkedin

(Prior to asking this question I searched this meta for "Know someone who can answer" and "LinkedIn".)

This is a blurb at the end of a Question:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

Perhaps we could add LinkedIn as well? A lot of professionals, including attorneys, paralegals, law students, etc. use LinkedIn.

Comment: I guess they can switch the experiment back on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83722/share-question-answer-links-to-linkedin?rq=1

Comment: Other previous possible duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116730/why-cant-we-share-on-linkedin-anymore/116732#116732

Comment: I did search before I posted...

Comment: I'm not saying you didn't but I can't determine that as you didn't include any of that research in your question.

Comment: added that info